# Rails: Getting column value from query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Seems like it should be able to look at a simple tutorial or find an aswer with a quick google, but I can't...

```
codes = PartnerCode.find_by_sql "SELECT * from partner_codes where product = 'SPANMEX' and isused = 'false' limit 1"
```

I want the column named code, I want just the value.  Tried everything what that seems logical.  Driving me nuts because everything I find shows an example without referencing the actual values returned

So what is the object returned?  Array, hash, ActiveRecord?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this one

```
Partner.where( conditions ).map(&:code)
```

is shorthand for

```
Partner.where( conditions ).map{|p| p.code}
```

PS

if you are often run into such case you will like this gem [valium by ernie](https://github.com/ernie/valium)

it gives you pretty way to get values without instantiating activerecord object like

```
Partner.where( conditions ).value_of :code
```

UPDATED:

if you need access some attribute and after that update record

save instance first in some variable:

```
instance=Partner.where( conditions ).first
```

then you may access attributes like `instance.code` and update some attribute

`instance.update_attribute || instance.update_attributes`

check documentation at [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) for details

Comment: OK, closer...  I'm not getting more than 1 result because I can't put the limit in the condition.

Comment: that works!  OK, to make things a bit more complicated...  I need to update that same record...  without the id or an ActiveRecord object, do I need to query again?

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 4+ (and a bit earlier I think), use `pluck`:

```
Partner.where(conditions).pluck :code
> ["code1", "code2", "code3"]
```

map is inefficient as it will select all columns first and also won't be able to optimise the query.